# Accessing the front facing camera. iPhone/iPod 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

Hey I was wondering how I can access the front facing camera. Maybe there's some guide for it?
But I don't want all buttons etc. I just want to access the from facing camera, I don't ant the button to take a photo or anything like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access the front facing camera like:

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Check out the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `cameraDevice` property of `UIImagePickerController` to  [`UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear). But you should check if the device is available.

Answer (score 2):

You should initiate an AVCaptureSession and specify which AVCaptureDevice to use ( AVCaptureDevicePositionFront in your case).

Start looking for the AVCaptureSession documentation and you should have a better understanding of what to do.

Comment: hey do you have any sample code to access the front camera using AVCaptureDevice?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what "Khushbu Shah" said is right. however actually the isCameraDeviceAvailable is available only ios 4 and above. Just to ensure that you opened the front camera only if it is there, the right code block to be used is as follows.

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.delegate = self;
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    if([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(isCameraDeviceAvailable:)])
    { //check if iphone 4 and above
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])
        {
            ipc.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        }
    }
}

[ipc release];
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to detect if your device has got front-facing camera. For  that you need to iterate through the video devices.

Try this method of `UIImagePickerController`:

```
+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)cameraDevice
```

This is a class method and UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice can take two values:

```
- UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear
- UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront
```

### Example code:

```
if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: all you have to do is open your Camera to be in Front Mode instead of Rear Mode, so write this inside the method where you call the picker for the first time:

        picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

      Hope this answers your question.