# Record video from front facing camera in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the front facing camera. iPhone/iPod 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729739/accessing-the-front-facing-camera-iphone-ipod-4)

How to record the video from front facing camera of the device in iPhone.

To use the front facing camera,We use this:

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

But how to create the video from that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can record Video from front facing camera in iphone like:-

```
-(IBAction)cameraLibraryButtonClick:(id)sender{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {              
        UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];  
        videoRecorder.delegate = self;
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];
        NSLog(@"Available types for source as camera = %@", sourceTypes);
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                            message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }
        videoRecorder.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
        videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;

        self.imagePicker = videoRecorder;                 
        [videoRecorder release];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
        newMedia = YES;
    }
    else {
        [self displaysorceError];
    }


}
```