# Video recording in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, video-recording

I am trying to implement functionality like below

**Final Recorded Video** = "**Capture a video from front camera** + **Record an audio from video** (*which I am playing through video player*)".

For more understanding please see the attach screen shot.

[image]

Using my blocks of codes which is given below: **At the end what I get is A video but without audio.**

But what I want to trying to implement is "**Final recorded video** which must be **combination** of: '**A video which is captured from my front camera** + **Record only audio from video file which I am playing**.'"

How can I achieve above functionality?

This is my code.

"**Recording**" Button Click Method is as following:

```
-(void) startRecording
{
    [self initCaptureSession];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"video"
                                         ofType:@"mp4"]];
    [self playMovieAtURL:url];

    [self startVideoRecording];
}
```

"**initCaptureSession**" : Using this method I am recording a video using front camera using 
"AVCaptureSession"

```
-(void) initCaptureSession
{
    NSLog(@"Setting up capture session");
    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Adding video input");

    AVCaptureDevice *VideoDevice = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];

    if (VideoDevice)
    {
        NSError *error;
        videoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error)
        {
            if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoInputDevice])
            {
                [captureSession addInput:videoInputDevice];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
    }


    NSLog(@"Adding audio input");
    AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeMuxed];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
    if (audioInput)
    {
        [captureSession addInput:audioInput];
    }


    NSLog(@"Adding movie file output");
    movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;    //<<SET MIN FREE SPACE IN BYTES FOR RECORDING TO CONTINUE ON A VOLUME

    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:movieFileOutput])
        [captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];

    [self CameraSetOutputProperties];           //(We call a method as it also has to be done after changing camera)

    NSLog(@"Setting image quality");
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    if ([captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])     //Check size based configs are supported before setting them
        [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

    [captureSession startRunning];
}

- (void) CameraSetOutputProperties
{
    AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection = nil;

    NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"5.0.0" options: NSNumericSearch];
    if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending) {
        // OS version >= 5.0.0
        CaptureConnection = [movieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    } else {
        // OS version < 5.0.0
        CaptureConnection = [self connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[movieFileOutput connections]];
    }

    //Set landscape (if required)
    if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    {
        AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation =  AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;// AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;      //<<<<<SET VIDEO ORIENTATION IF LANDSCAPE
        [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];
    }
 }
```

"**-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL** " By using this method I am playing a video

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL
{
player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[player prepareToPlay];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver: self
 selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
 name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object: player];
player.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 200);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];

[player play];
}
```

"**startVideoRecording**" using this method I have started recording the Final video.

```
- (void) startVideoRecording
{
    //Create temporary URL to record to
    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO)
        {
            //Error - handle if required
            NSLog(@"file remove error");
        }
    }
    //Start recording
    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
                error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

    BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr)
    {
        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value)
        {
            RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }
    if (RecordedSuccessfully)
    {
        //----- RECORDED SUCCESSFULLY -----
        NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
        {
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"File save error");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     recordedVideoURL=assetURL;
                 }
             }];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *assetURL=[self copyFileToDocuments:outputFileURL];
            if(assetURL!=nil)
            {
                recordedVideoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:assetURL];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check Out This Link if it help http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Comment: +1 for nice answer formatting :)

Comment: Hi..is that can record live rtsp streaming also ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**// Add some extra code for following methods** "1st Method"

```
  -(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL

    {
       [player play];
       AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
       NSError *err = nil;
       [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
     if(err)
      {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo]     description]);
        return;
    }
       [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
       err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

       recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

      [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
      [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
      [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
      recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
     NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);
     audio_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
    err = nil;
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[audio_url path] options: 0 error:&err];
    if(audioData)
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[audio_url path] error:&err];
    }

    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audio_url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder)
    {
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable)
    {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        return;
    }


}
```

**// 2nd method**

```
-(void) stopVideoRecording

    {
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player stop];
    [movieFileOutput stopRecording];

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_url options:nil];
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:outputURL options:nil];

    mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration)
                                        ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                                         atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                                   ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                          presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:videoTrack.preferredTransform];
}
```

**// Final Play Video**

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:mixComposition];
AVPlayer *player1 = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player1];
[playerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:playerLayer];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[player1 play];
player1.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Comment: can you please post whole code on github ..? so that it will be easy for us to get exact demo for use

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you..

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionCommentaryTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration) 
                                    ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) 
                               ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] 
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition 
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   

NSString* videoName = @"export.mov";

NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL    *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}

_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
DLog(@"file type %@",_assetExport.outputFileType);
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {      
            // your completion code here
     }       
 }
 ];
```

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456565/1865424

and you can also check the code for recording video from front camera.

```
-(IBAction)cameraLibraryButtonClick:(id)sender{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {              
        UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];  
        videoRecorder.delegate = self;
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];
        NSLog(@"Available types for source as camera = %@", sourceTypes);
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                            message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }
        videoRecorder.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
        videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;

        self.imagePicker = videoRecorder;                 
        [videoRecorder release];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
        newMedia = YES;
    }
    else {
        [self displaysorceError];
    }


}
```

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154289/1865424

If these doesn't work for you..Let me know..But i think this will help you out..

Comment: Want to implement video and audio record within iphone screen ,thanks

Comment: this will help you out.@MacGeek