# 'No available types for source 1' when the app runs on my device(IPhone 6) swift

Tags: ios, xcode6

This all of a sudden,but when I run the following method it throws a 'No available types for source 1' Error, I've looked every where and people say its cuz its in a simulator well I'm running it on my iPhone 6. any clue why?

```
func captureVideo(){
    if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
    var date = NSDate()


    var picker = UIImagePickerController()


    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    picker.mediaTypes = NSArray(objects: kUTTypeVideo)
    var interval = NSTimeInterval(30)
    picker.videoMaximumDuration = interval
    picker.showsCameraControls = true;

    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Another thing is that the UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) is returning true

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the issue is with:

```
picker.mediaTypes = NSArray(objects: kUTTypeVideo)
```

Change it to:

```
picker.mediaTypes = NSArray(objects: kUTTypeMovie)
```

For video recording use `kUTTypeMovie` not `kUTTypeVideo`.

---

According to [UIImagePickerController mediaTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes):

> If you set this property to an empty array, or to an array in which
>   none of the media types is available for the current source, the
>   system throws an exception.

It is better to use [**availableMediaTypesForSourceType:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/availableMediaTypesForSourceType:) before assigning any value to mediaTypes.

Comment: Is there a way to record video without audio and not request the microphone permission?  How /when would you use kUTTypeVideo?

Comment: @NV: You can use AVFoundation for this, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102078/video-recording-in-iphone-sdk-programatically